# Stakater Reloader - errors in pod logs on startup in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to get [Stakater Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) working on a Kubernetes cluster. Installed [the stable release](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/reloader) via Helm. Annotated my deployments as per the instructions but rolling updates didn't happen when I changed ConfigMaps. When I checked the reloader pod logs I found this:

```
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=info msg="Environment:Kubernetes"
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=info msg="Starting Reloader"
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=warning msg="KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE is unset, will detect changes in all namespaces."
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=info msg="Starting Controller to watch resource type: secrets"
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=info msg="Starting Controller to watch resource type: configMaps"
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=error msg="Failed to list deployments the server could not find the requested resource"
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=error msg="Failed to list daemonSets the server could not find the requested resource"
time="2019-12-13T15:46:02Z" level=error msg="Failed to list statefulSets the server could not find the requested resource"
```

Then the last 3 lines just repeat periodically.

I'm wondering if its an RBAC issue, but the ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding seem to be there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How was your Kubernetes cluster created? Is it bare metal one, or cloud provisioned?

Comment: The master is on a VM and the nodes are bare metal.

Comment: How was it created? Kubeadm, Guide: Kubernetes the hard way?

Comment: @JamesB which k8s version are you using? It looks like an api mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Reloader version in the stable Helm repository does not support Kubernetes 1.16.x.

See [here](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader/issues/118#issuecomment-570527755) for workaround.